# PHP и MySQL. Сортировка ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql

На главной странице есть кнопки, обрабатывающие один и тот же запрос, но с разным условием поиска

```
(select id, name from table where yx=1; select id, name from table where yx=2...)
```

Обрабатываются и выводятся результаты запроса на отдельной странице. 
Подскажите как можно результирующий список сортировать?

Comment: используйте `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 2):

Добавить в конец запроса конструкцию ORDER BY:

```
select id, name from table where yx=1 ORDER BY id ASC;
```

ASC - сортирует по возрастанию
DESC - сортирует по убыванию

Можно так же комбинировать поля и способы их сортировки:

```
select id, name from table where yx=1 ORDER BY id ASC, name DESC;
```

Comment: Ну это понятно. Но я имел в виду сортировать результирующий список.
Т.е запрос прошел, вывелся результат, но пользователь решил отсортировать, например, по дате или цене эти результаты.

Comment: jquery плагин, datatables например

Comment: @Chromegolf, так же через ORDER BY и сортируй. Например, создаешь форму с селектами, и в зависимости от выбранного селекта делаешь запрос на вывод:

    select id, name from table where yx=1 ORDER BY date DESC;
    select id, name from table where yx=1 ORDER BY price DESC;

А иначе, если селекты не выбраны, делаешь ту выборку, какую необходимо.

Comment: Только не стоит забывать о безопасности и передавать сортируемое поле в запросе. Лучше сделать селект с id а на сервере уже с помощью swtich выбрать поле по которому нужно сортировать.