# Не могу отсортировать массив PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Проблема заключается в следующем: собирая информацию о баллах студентов из разных таблиц, я собираю их в одно целое:

```
$sql="SELECT `u`.`login` as `login`, `u`.`dostup` as `dostup`, `u`.`fac` as `fac`,
(SELECT SUM(`h`.`mark`) FROM `homework` as `h` WHERE `h`.`student`=`u`.`login` and `status` != '0' and `status` != '2') as `sumh`,
(SELECT COUNT(`h`.`id`) FROM `homework` as `h` WHERE `h`.`student`=`u`.`login` and `status` != '0' and `status` != '2') as `counth`,
(SELECT SUM(`r`.`mark`) FROM `reports` as `r` WHERE `r`.`student`=`u`.`login` and `status` != '0' and `status` != '2') as `sumr`,
(SELECT COUNT(`r`.`id`) FROM `reports` as `r` WHERE `r`.`student`=`u`.`login` and `status` != '0' and `status` != '2') as `countr`,
(SELECT SUM(`a`.`ball`) FROM `adminball` as `a` WHERE `a`.`student`=`u`.`login`) as `suma`,
(SELECT SUM(`ocena`) FROM `exam` WHERE `stud`=`u`.`login`) as `exam`,
(SELECT SUM(`ball`) FROM `penalty` WHERE `student`=`u`.`login`) as `penalty`
FROM `users` as `u` WHERE `u`.`fac` != '-' and `u`.`dostup` > 0 and `u`.`dostup` < 6  GROUP BY `u`.`id` HAVING `counth`>0 or `countr`>0";
```

И в итоге, когда я далее вывожу уже список, у меня получаются цифры не по порядку, а вразброс. Не могу добиться сортировки массива (числа по убыванию).

```
$res = mysql_query($sql);

$i = 1;
$result = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $sum=$row['sumh']+$row['sumr']+$row['suma']+$row['exam']-$row['penalty'];

    $count=$row['counth']+$row['countr'];
    if ($result[0]['sum'] < $sum) {
        array_unshift($result, array('sum'=>$sum, 'count'=>$count, 'fac'=>$row['fac'], 'login'=>$row['login'], 'sumh/counth'=>$row['sumh']/$row['counth'], 'dostup'=>$row['dostup']));
    }else{
        $result[] = array('sum'=>$sum, 'count'=>$count, 'fac'=>$row['fac'], 'login'=>$row['login'], 'sumh/counth'=>$row['sumh']/$row['counth'], 'dostup'=>$row['dostup']);
    }

    $i++;
}

foreach($result as $i => $row) {
    echo "<tr><td> <font color='#C88900'><center>".($i+1)."</font> </center></td><td> <a title='". $point[$row['fac']] ."'><font color='". $colorsfac[$row['fac']] ."'> <center>".$row['login']."</center> </font></a></td><td><center><font color='#C88900'>";
    if($row['dostup'] and $row['fac'] == "Прешт") {
        echo "-";
    } else {
        echo "$row[dostup]-й курс</font> </center></td>";
    }

    echo "<td><center><font color='#9B6B03'> ".$row['sum']."</font> </center></td><td><center><font color='#C88900'> ".round($row['sumh/counth'], 1)." </font></center></td><td><center><font color='#C88900'> ".$row['count']."</font> </center></td></tr>";
}
```

В итоге цифры выводятся вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите! **ORDER BY НЕ ПОМОГАЕТ И НЕ СОРТИРУЕТ БАЛЛЫ.**

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/236234/php-%D0%B8-mysql-%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-order-by

Comment: Почему бы не добавить в SQL-запрос конструкцию ORDER BY и не отсортировать результирующую таблицу по выражению ORDER BY sumh + sumr + suma + exam - penalty DESC ?

Comment: Ну оно и правильно, выже любое значения болшее первого элемента в конец дописываете. http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php в помощ.

Comment: "ORDER BY sumh + sumr + suma + exam - penalty DESC " ничего не меняет. Поэтому этот не помогает, увы.

Comment: А что происходит когда вы пытаетесь применить order by, он просто обязан отсортировать, если формула задана правильная. Надеюсь когда вы его используете вы убираете все попытки отсортировать в php и выводите в том порядке как вернула БД